# Writing URLs via Beautifulsoup to a csv file vertically

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I have a project for one of my college classes that requires me to pull all URLs from a page on the U.S. census bureau website and store them in a CSV file.  For the most part I've figured out how to do that but for some reason when the data gets appended to the CSV file, all the entries are being inserted horizontally.  I would expect the data to be arranged vertically, meaning row 1 has the first item in the list, row 2 has the second item and so on.  I have tried several approaches but the data always ends up as a horizontal representation.  I am new to python and obviously don't have a firm enough grasp on the language to figure this out. Any help would be greatly fully appreciated.

I am parsing the website using Beautifulsoup4  and the request library.  Pulling all the 'a' tags from the website was easy enough and getting the URLs from those 'a' tags into a list was pretty clear as well.  But when I append the list to my CSV file with a writerow function, all the data ends up in one row as opposed to one separate row for each URL.

```
import requests
import csv
requests.get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

page = requests.get('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

## Create Link to append web data to
links = []

# Pull text from all instances of <a> tag within BodyText div
AllLinks = soup.find_all('a')

for link in AllLinks:
    links.append(link.get('href'))

with open("htmlTable.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(links)

pprint(links)
```

Comment: please add your imports to make it a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
## Create Link to append web data to
links = []

# Pull text from all instances of <a> tag within BodyText div
AllLinks = soup.find_all('a')

for link in AllLinks:
    links.append(link.get('href'))

with open("htmlTable.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for link in links:
        if (isinstance(link, str)):
            f.write(link + "\n",)
```

I changed it to check whether a given link was indeed a string and if so, add a newline after it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew that did it!

Answer (score 1):

Try making a list of lists, by appending the url inside a list

```
links.append([link.get('href')])
```

Then the csv writer will put each list on a new line with writerows

```
writer.writerows(links)
```